# removeAttr(x) vs. attr(x, '') in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there generally a difference between `removeAttr(x)` and `attr(x, '')` in jQuery?

If so, when to use each one?

Answer (score 9):

Given that the defninition of removeAttr from the jQuery library (see below). I'd say yes.

```
removeAttr: function( name, fn ) {
        return this.each(function(){
            jQuery.attr( this, name, "" );
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
                this.removeAttribute( name );
            }
        });
```

Source: [Jquery 1.4.3 uncompressed version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js)

Although it is inherently subjective. I think using removeAttr is a more self-documenting approach. However, I could see other people thinking the opposite.

Comment: They are different, by that very code -- for elements, it sets attr to '' *AND* (for elements) removes the attribute from the DOM.

Comment: @pst - Point taken. I changed "No" to "yes"

Comment: Of course, it's quite late, but check @john-strickler response. Setting an attribute to empty leaves it in the tag, so it's "present". This is important for attributes that are used as flags, like `disabled` and others.

Answer (score 6):

They are quite different operations:

**attr(x, '')** sets an attribute to an empty string

**removeAttr(x)** deletes the property on the object if possible, or removes it and resets it to its default value if it is defined by the DTD for that object class.

Answer (score 3):

`.removeAttr(x);` is equivalent to `.removeAttribute("x");` while `.attr(x, '')` simply sets `.x` to an empty string. See the [jQuery `removeAttr` ref](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and the corresponding [mozilla `removeAttribute` ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Some attributes are booleans (whether they exist or don't exist).  Take the attribute `disabled` for example.  If it exists then its true, it doesn't matter what the value is set to.  So you'd have to use `.removeAttr('disabled')` to enable the element again.  However, jQuery does normalize it a bit, you could use `.attr('disabled', false);`  So I guess the answer is semantics.

**Edit:**

This answer just got some upvotes which alerted that I answered this several years ago.

Use this instead for properties -

```
.prop('disabled', true) // set as disabled
.prop('disabled', false) // set as enabled
.prop('disabled') // return boolean (is this disabled?)
```

**DO NOT** use removeProp('disabled') as this will delete the property from the DOM object (which is not what you are intending to do).

Answer (score 3):

First difference:

```
.removeAttr('name')  // try to remove the attribute 'name' from the DOM
.attr('name', '')    // set the attribute 'name' to empty string
```

The second difference, probably happened only to me, is `.removeAttr()` work correctly in Firefox and IExplorer but not very well in Chrome and don't work at all on Safari.