# jquery loop function; hide div if

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a new website (music magazine) and I need to use a very handy function; i have a rough idea how to do it but cannot get the code to work.

In the review section I want to display one main CD review and other CDs just mentioned with the titles in the sidebar div. Now I don't want the main display CD to be listed in the sidebar at the same time. I am trying to write a jquery function which will hide the title from the sidebar as soon as it matches the main display CDs title.

I guess the idea is to create an if function here: `if (main CD title) == (sidebar CD title)` hide the (sidebar that contains the CD title); it has to loop through all elements automatically.

Below is the sample of the code that is affected:

html:

```
<div class="grid_12 alpha omega upper2" title="vil">
<div class="grid_8 upper alpha omega" id="vil">
```

grid_12 is the main CD and grid_8 is the sidebar title CD

jquery bit:

```
if($('.grid_12').attr('title') == $('.grid_8').attr('title'))
{
$('.grid_8').attr('title').hide();
}
```

The jquery code is definitely wrong but it is just the idea how i wanna do it.

The suggestion with putting all unique ids into an array is quite good.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Jacek

Comment: Sounds nice. What's the question then?

Comment: And what's your (relevant) HTML?

Comment: Get all cd titles in the sidebar and add to an array. Then check the array to see if the main cd title matches or validate off each one and leave out the array. You really need to post some code for us to help; html & attempted js.

Comment: Put your code in the question itself, nobody can read it squadged into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide title, it's meaningless. You can hide an element, or clear its title.

So change to either one of those and it will "work":

```
$('.grid_8').hide();
```

Or:

```
$('.grid_8').attr('title', '');
```

Reading what you said again, I think I understand your goal. Such code will hide element with class "grid_8" having title the same as element with class "grid_12":

```
var titleToSearch = $('.grid_12').attr('title');
var matchingDiv = $('.grid_8[title="' + titleToSearch + '"]');
matchingDiv.hide();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/7DhGh/).

This assumes you have only one "grid_12" and several "grid_8" elements. If you have more than one and each "grid_12" contains several "grid_8" and you want to find one of them with matching title, here is updated code:

```
var parentGrid12 = $(this).parents(".grid_12");
var titleToSearch = parentGrid12.attr("title");
var matchingDiv = parentGrid12.find(".grid_8[title='" + titleToSearch + "']");
matchingDiv.hide();
```

The `$(this)` assumes the code is being executed as event handler of some element inside "grid_12". [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DhGh/1/).

Comment: I suppose `.removeAttr( 'title' )` would be more appropriate. Probably doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: @Juhana see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4217437/447356). Not sure myself, leaving it be for now.

Comment: $('.grid_8').attr('title', ''); would probably make more sense; i can't really use $('.grid_8').hide(); as this will hide all divs with that class and there are quite a few on the page; the idea is to hide only one .grid_8 div, that contains a given attribute.

Comment: Shadow Wizard: you are absolutely correct; that's exactly what I wanted to do. I only have one grid_12 element and multiple grid_8, one of which I want to hide. Will test the above code and see if it's working. Thanks for your help. btw. both grid_12 and the targeted grid_8 also have other classes on top of them; would that affect the function in any way? i.e. "grid_12 alpha omega" + "grid_12 alpha omega upper"

Comment: just to let you know; it works fine. thanks for your help once again :)